# Windows forms generate text boxes dynamically by given value

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, matrix, textbox

What I'm trying to do is, for ex, if I passed 5 as `matrSize` then it must generate 25 textboxes named MatrixNode[11], .. MatrixNode[12]... (just like matrix in math) like this

[image]

The text boxes will just get matrix elements, but by default random values will be filled in right after text box creation.

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(int matrSize)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            int counter=0;
            TextBox[] MatrixNodes = new TextBox[matrSize*matrSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < matrSize; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrSize; j++)
                {
                    var tb = new TextBox();
                    Random r = new Random();
                    int num = r.Next(1, 1000);
                    MatrixNodes[counter] = tb;
                    tb.Name = "Node_" + MatrixNodes[counter];
                    tb.Text = num.ToString();
                    tb.Location = new Point(172, 32 + (i * 28));
                    tb.Visible = true;
                    this.Controls.Add(tb);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            Debug.Write(counter);
        }
```

Now the problem is:

1. My function fills same number to all generated fields (don't know reason), in fact it must be random
2. The look must be exactly as matrix in math, I mean, for ex, if we passed value 5, there must be 5 rows and 5 columns of textboxes. But I get only 5 textbox vertically.

Thx in advance. Please help to figure out function

Comment: Suggest to use a DataGridView instead of textboxes. Then you can easy iterate trough all DataGridViewCells for reading values. For example: Passed value 5 -> add 5 columns and 5 rows to DataGridView. You can hide a headers of columns and rows, and it is looks as textboxes. Sure it is more effective in this case....

Answer (score 3):

1. You are creating a new instance of `Random` each iteration and those are very close in time, that's why values are the same. Create one instance *before* external `for` cycle and just call `Next()` inside.
2. All your `Point` instances have the same horizontal position 172, so all your columns overlap. You need to adjust X using the `j` variable, something like `Point(172 + (j * 28), 32 + (i * 28))`.

Comment: Edited my answer to include 2 as well.

Comment: How about textbox naming, how can I name them like in math matrix?

Comment: You have 'i' and 'j' which are zero-based column and row indices of this matrix, so naming might look simply like this: tb.Name = string.Format("Node_{0}{1}", i+1, j+1);

Answer (score 0):

For question 2:

You are setting the textbox location as:

```
tb.Location = new Point(172, 32 + (i * 28)
```

and never changing the X coordinate (172) so you will only get one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int matrSize = 4;
    int counter = 0;
    TextBox[] MatrixNodes = new TextBox[matrSize * matrSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrSize; j++)
        {
            var tb = new TextBox();
            Random r = new Random();
            int num = r.Next(1, 1000);
            MatrixNodes[counter] = tb;
            tb.Name = "Node_" + MatrixNodes[counter];
            tb.Text = num.ToString();
            tb.Location = new Point(172 + (j * 150), 32 + (i * 50));
            tb.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(tb);
            counter++;
        }

        counter = 0;
    }
}
```